# Using Holoviews AdjointLayout with Bokeh cannot get right plot to zoom the vertical axis with box zoom in the main panel

Tags: bokeh, holoviews

I am using Holoviews 1.16.2, I setup an AdjointLayout with

```
new_layout=(((plot_1*plot_2*event_plot) * hv.Overlay(hlines)*overlay)<< (plot_5*plot_3) << plot_4)
new_layout=new_layout.opts(opts.Layout(title=f'{eval_date_ticker.result[0]}',shared_axes=True))
```

plot_1 is hv.Points, plot_2 is hv.Curve, plot_3 is hv.Spikes, plot_4 is hv.Spikes, plot_5 is hv.Histogram, event_plot is hv.Points

This yields the following chart:

[image: Unzoomed Plots]

I can Use the Box Zoom tool to zoom in on window in the main panel.  This also zooms the top panel to match the same range. Both of these frames have Time on the X Axis.

I can not find a way to get the right panel to zoom in a similar manner. In this case the right side pane has it's x-axis in a vertical orientation and ideally it would zoom with the y-axis selected range from the main panel.

This is what actually happens.

[image: Only Top Plot Zooms]

Here are the details of the plots:

```
plot_1 :Points   [index,Adj_Close]   (Adj_Close,NumQuotes,Dollars,NumTrades,Event_Date_Time,Adj_Close_Scaled_1)
plot_2 :Curve   [index]   (Adj_Close,Event_Date_Time)
plot_3 :Spikes   [Adj_Close]   (Dollars,Adj_Close,Event_Date_Time,NumTrades,NumQuotes,Adj_Close_Scaled_1)
plot_4 :Spikes   [index]   (Trade_Size,Dollars,Adj_Close,NumTrades,Event_Date_Time,NumQuotes)
plot_5 :Histogram   [x]   (Dollars)
hlines [:HLine   [x,y], :HLine   [x,y], :HLine   [x,y], :HLine   [x,y], :HLine   [x,y], :HLine   [x,y], :HLine   [x,y], :HLine   [x,y], :HLine   [x,y], :HLine   [x,y], :HLine   [x,y], :HLine   [x,y]]
overlay :Overlay
   .Text.I    :Text   [x,y]
   .Text.II   :Text   [x,y]
   .Text.III  :Text   [x,y]
   .Text.IV   :Text   [x,y]
   .Text.V    :Text   [x,y]
   .Text.VI   :Text   [x,y]
   .Text.VII  :Text   [x,y]
   .Text.VIII :Text   [x,y]
   .Text.IX   :Text   [x,y]
   .Text.X    :Text   [x,y]
   .Text.XI   :Text   [x,y]
   .Text.XII  :Text   [x,y]
event_plot :Points   [index,Plot_Height]   (Event_Date_Time,Grade,ProgType,BckGrnd,S1,S2,CS,CB,CT,Size)
```

The code that generates the histogram plot is as follows:

```
hist, edges = np.histogram(plot_df_events1['Adj_Close'], bins=100, weights=plot_df_events1['Dollars'])
plot_5 = hv.Histogram((edges, hist),vdims=['Dollars'],label='')
plot_5.opts(width=200, height=600, xlabel='Adj_Close', ylabel='Dollars', tools=['hover'],alpha=.25,color='grey',shared_axes=True)
```

Any insight would be appreciated.  I have tried a large number of things without success.

Comment: Further experimentation indicates that if I eliminate plot_5 (the histogram) the link functionality works. So a solution to what changes need to be made to the histogram to maintain function would be much appreciated.